# Как затриггерить js функцию на сайте, при помощи питон? Парсинг

Tags: javascript, python, html, парсер

**Всем привет!** Я столкнулся с такой проблемой, при #парсинге сайта, мне нужно собирать ссылки и текст, но проблема заключается в том, что ссылка не прописана напрямую, а через #js функцию в #html коде, то грубо говоря, мне нужно затригерить js функцию передавая ей параметры. И да, мне нужно именно вызвать эту функцию (хз как). Selenium я юзать не могу, код я пишу на #Python

**Я впервые на форуме, и начинаю только осваивать парсин, буду очень признателен за ответ**

```js
    function submit(key, title, value)
    {
        var url = document.location.href;
        if (document.location.href.indexOf('#') != -1)
            url = document.location.href.substring(0, document.location.href.indexOf('#'));
        if (value != '')
            document.location.href = url + "#" + value;
        else
            document.location.href = url;
        var form = document.getElementById('PostForm');
        form.innerHTML = "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"Key\">";
        form.innerHTML += "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"Title\">";
        document.forms[1].Key.value = key;
        document.forms[1].Title.value = title;
        document.forms[1].action = "Groups.aspx";
        document.forms[1].submit();
    }
```

```html
<a href="javascript:submit('RJuzPlvdavwzyOu12R7PKQ==','название товара....','0');">название товара....</a>
```

Comment: В целом, зная URL, который парсится, функцию можно реализовать локально(как обходной вариант) и понять, на какой URL будет переправлен пользователь. Единственное, сама эта фукнция в какой то форме создает 2 инпута, туда присваивает ключ и название и отправяет эту форму на Groups.aspx

Comment: Метод sumbit() формирует обычную форму, которая отправляет данные методом POST (судя по id формы) на URL Groups.aspx, парсите параметры метода, и делаете обычный POST запрос с нужными данными.

Comment: Грубо говоря, я должен сделать POST запрос с параметрами на URL Groups.aspx?

Comment: Просто я не до конца понимаю что такое Groups.aspx))

Comment: @VeRteX консоль браузера вам в помощь.  Groups.aspx это путь относительно текущего url, т.е. если текущий url https://localhost/some/path/to/folder , то ваш целевой URL будет https://localhost/some/path/to/folder/Groups.aspx . Но самый простой вариант, это посмотреть в консоли браузера, что, куда, и как отправляется.